# How to send a function to another process in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, process

I have 2 processes, one of them has to communicate with the other one.
It needs to send a function so that the other one can execute it many times.
Can it be done using shared memory, so that the sender writes the function instructions
and the receiver reads them and executes? If so, how can I get the function's binary instructions?
Is there another way to do it?
I need to do it on a Linux distribution.

Comment: Why send the function? Why not just have the function on the other end from the start? I can see what you're trying to do being quite difficult.

Comment: This might be vaguely possible. But the difficulty is so high that there must be a better way to do it. What you probably really want is to have a process with all the functions you want already compiled into it, then use an RPC protocol to send a function ID (just a number) and the arguments over some kind of socket, then wait for the results. `gRPC` might work for you.

Comment: This is not really possible in the way you envision it here. Perhaps if you describe what you need at a higher level we can come up with an approach that would work.

Comment: Could you explain the underlying problem you're trying to solve here? This sounds like a very difficult thing to achieve so there might be a better way to achieve what you want otherwise.

Comment: sounds like a xy problem. Probably the tag C can be removed, even that does not change a lot the problem ...

Comment: You could have 1 process write a shard library, and then have another process dynamically load that library.  This would be a bad idea and very slow.  Although this question is about c++, you could consider using some kind of evaluated scripting language inside c++.  Then the two processes only need to send/receive strings.

Comment: do a bidirectional communication allowing process1 to ask process2 to ask process1 to do a funcall also giving it the arguments then to give back to process2 the result ...and may be allowing process2 to give that result back to process1 even it already had it ? May be there are simpler ways to do ^^Just pry also the funcall does not have memory effect on process1 ... Clearly a xy problem !

Comment: @500-InternalServerError
OK, here's the bigger picture:
I am trying to do a MapReduce simulator on the same machine as the processes that are using it. The MapReduce engine has to be a separate process. It needs to be able to receive routines from other processes - `map` and `reduce` at least.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want well, you can have to threads and a global `std::promise` to send a function from one thread to another one, as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
int main(){

    std::promise<std::function<void(int)>> functionToBeSent;
    std::thread process1{[&]{
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        functionToBeSent.set_value([](int arg){std::cout << arg << "\n";});
    }};

    std::thread process2 {
        [&] {
            auto future = functionToBeSent.get_future();
            while ( future.wait_for(100ms)!=std::future_status::ready);
            auto functionToBeExecutedManyTimes = future.get();
            int manyTimes = 100;
            while(manyTimes--) {
                functionToBeExecutedManyTimes(manyTimes);
            }

        }
    };

    process1.join();
    process2.join();

}
```